# ICompileModule with ASP.NET Core (RC2)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, aspnet-compiler

ASP.NET Core RC2 do not using `dnx`, how i can use `ICompileModule`? Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

This feature was removed in `dotnet` toolchain.

In github issue: [Preprocess files are beeing ignored](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1812) David Fowler says:

> Yea this feature is dead and isn't coming back unfortunately.

But it seems that some work around this is being done:

> The Roslyn source generator feature work is actually well under way

Here is a feature proposal in roslyn repo: [[Proposal] enable code generating extensions to the compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5561). There is also a mention of [Generators in the docs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/12bd769ebcd3121b88f535e8559f5a42d9c0e873/docs/features/generators.md), a [Checklist of work](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/ed773e27e525719c8ffd932843aa41dfba5b167e/docs/features/generators.work.md) and a [`features/source-generators` branch](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/CommandLine).

Comment: * **David** Fowler